# WebdriverIO config file for multiple browsers

Tags: selenium, testing, e2e-testing, webdriver-io, browser-testing

I need to run test cases on multiple browsers, while using webdriverIO. Despite going through several articles and documentation of WDIO, I couldn't find a way in which works.

this is my wdio.conf.js.

```js
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8100/',
    path: '/wd/hub',
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*-wdio.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    maxInstances: 10,
    // capabilities: [
    //   {
    //       browserName: 'Chrome',
    //   }, 
    //   {
    //       browserName: 'Firefox',
    //   }
    // ],
    capabilities: {
        myChromeBrowser: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'Chrome',
            }
        },
        myFirefoxBrowser: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'Firefox',
            }
        }
    },
    
    sync: true,
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000,
        expectationResultHandler: function(passed, assertion) {  }
    },
    before: function () {
        require('ts-node/register');
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e'
        });
    },
}
```

These are the devDependencies I have used in package.json:

```js
"devDependencies": {
   "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
   "wdio-appium-service": "^0.2.3",
   "wdio-firefox-profile-service": "^0.1.0",
   "wdio-jasmine-framework": "^0.3.2",
   "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.9",
   "wdio-spec-reporter": "^0.1.2",
   "wdio-typescript-service": "0.0.3",
   "webdriverio": "^4.9.8"
}
```

As you can see, I have tried both `"capabilities": []` and `"capabilities": {}` but following [official docs](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/multiremote.html), and even after that, only `two instances of Chrome` run. I have also tried installing `Firefox's` plugin/dependencies by following [installation doc](http://webdriver.io/guide/services/firefox-profile.html).

Can anybody point out, what have i missed or wrongly configured?
Currently **two instances of google Chrome** launches and the test cases run on them, while I want the test cases to run in chrome and firefox separately.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally please check your "Camel Casing" on your browser names. Because you have `Firefox` instead of `firefox` - you are probably having it launch the second instance of Chrome.

```
...
capabilities: [
{
    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    maxInstances: 1,
    browserName: 'chrome'
},
{
    maxInstances: 1,
    browserName: 'firefox'
}
],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you want multiple browser tests is to run a single test suite with different environment variables. You should define matrix like;

```
matrix:
- _BROWSER: "firefox"
  _PLATFORM: "Linux"
  _VERSION: "26"
- _BROWSER: "firefox"
  _PLATFORM: "Windows_7"
  _VERSION: "26"
- _BROWSER: "chrome"
  _PLATFORM: "Windows_7"
  _VERSION: "31"
```

then just create your WebdriverJS instance with given capacities

```
var BROWSERNAME = (process.env._BROWSER || process.env.BROWSER || 'chrome').replace(/_/g,' ');
var BROWSERVERSION = process.env._VERSION || process.env.VERSION || '*';
var BROWSERPLATFORM = (process.env._PLATFORM || process.env.PLATFORM || 'Linux').replace(/_/g,' ');

var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {


     browserName: BROWSERNAME,
        version: BROWSERVERSION,
        platform: BROWSERPLATFORM
    },
    // ...
};

client = webdriverjs.remote(options);
```

Travis will automatically start three different builds and will run your tests with different browser in parallel. Check out this example project for more implementation details.

For more details [multiple browsers test](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/150)